# ChildProcess in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create 4 child process using os.fork() method and then inside the parent process I want to list all the child process.
And also before terminating each child process I want that each child process must wait for 2 seconds.
I was successful in creating 4 child process. but couldn't list the child processes using parent process.
This is my code:

```
import os

for i in range(4):
  process = os.fork()

  if(process > 0):
```

Please Help in the above

Comment: The code snippet is incomplete

Comment: Do you actually need to use ``os.fork``? Python ships with *several* higher abstraction layers, most prominently the ``subprocess`` module.

Comment: Yes I actually need to use os.fork

Comment: @MisterMiyagi can You do it using sub process ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested pseudocode. But maybe it will help you somehow

```
import psutil
import os

for i in range(4):
  pid = os.fork()
  current_process = psutil.Process(pid)
  children = current_process.children(recursive=True)
  for child in children:
      print('Child pid is {}'.format(child.pid))
```

Comment: This is a very nice code but this is giving an error that no process is found using the pid 0.